# Attribute data from two points to one line

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, line, attribute-joins

I have exported GPS points into QGIS and I created individual lines between the points based on date. In each points attribute table I can find the speed. Now I want to join the attribute data from 2 points to 1 line, so that I have the speed of point 1 and the speed of point 2 in the lines attribute table. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried "Join attributes by location" twice?

Comment: You can use the option provided by @BERA. However, if you have multiple lines to join attributes to, you can create a graphical model. This you can ran as a batch process to join attributes for many lines. It can also be useful if it is a task you want to perform in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I used join attributes by location and it resulted in two lines between two points: one line with data from point A and one line with data from point B. Now I need the two lines to merge into one line (because they are the same). What is the right tool for that?